# Eloquent update doesn't work in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to make update function but the function doesn't work, plese help me for resolve this problem
this is my code :

This is Route

```
Route::resource('ItemName', 'ItemNameController');
```

This is Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, ItemName $itemName)
{
    request()->validate([
        'inc'            => 'required',
        'item_name'      => 'required',
        'short_name'     => 'required',
        'definition_eng' => 'max:1000', 
        'definition_ind' => 'max:1000',
    ]);

    $itemName->update($request->all());

    return redirect('ItemName')->with('success', 'Item Name Updated Successfully');
}
```

This is View

```
<form action="{{ action('ItemNameController@update', $ItemName->id) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <input class="form-control col-4" type="text" name="inc" placeholder="INC" value="{{$ItemName->inc}}">
    <input class="form-control mt-2" type="text" name="item_name" placeholder="Item Name" value="{{$ItemName->item_name}}">
    <input class="form-control mt-2" type="text" name="short_name" placeholder="Short Name" value="{{$ItemName->short_name}}">
    <input class="form-control mt-2" type="text" name="definition_eng" placeholder="English Definition" value="{{$ItemName->definition_eng}}">
    <input class="form-control mt-2" type="text" name="definition_ind" placeholder="Indonesia Definition" value="{{$ItemName->definition_ind}}">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit">
</form>
```

Value when i dump this code

```
ItemName {#512 ▼
#table: "tbl_item_name"
#fillable: array:5 [▼
0 => "inc"
1 => "item_name"
2 => "short_name"
3 => "definition_eng"
4 => "definition_ind"
]
#connection: "sqlsrv"
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: true
#attributes: array:8 [▶]
#original: array:8 [▶]
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#appends: []
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: []
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#guarded: array:1 [▼
0 => "*"
]
}
```

The Problem is update function is doesn't work, and i didn't get any error, can anyone help me?

Comment: “doesn’t work” – what error do you get? What happens? What used to happen?

Comment: What error you get and you update by which id?

Comment: where is your condition checking you are going to update which id or which Item?

Comment: There is no error, i got the alert of successful but delete function doesn't work @ThomasEdwards

Comment: can you help me sir, please? @MehravishTemkar

Comment: Is the route actually reaching the update method? If not, try changing `ItemName` to `item_name` in the resource controller binding.

Comment: Please post your Eloquent model for `ItemName`.

Comment: What's the result of `\DB::enableQueryLog(); $itemName->update($request->all()); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`?

Comment: just [ ] brother @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: What's the result of `dd($request->all());` and `dd($itemName->update($request->all()));`?

Answer (score 8):

Ensure the `$fillable` array is set correctly on your Eloquent model.

```
class ItemName extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'inc',
        'item_name',
        'short_name',
        'definition_eng',
        'definition_ind',
    ];

    // ..

}
```

Normally Laravel will create a `MassAssignmentException` if you call `update()` and have not defined the `$fillable` array.

As soon as you define anything on the `$fillable` array Laravel will silently ignore any additional values.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem

My update function in the controller is as follows

```php
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Person  $person
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Person $person, Request $request)
    {
        $person->update($request->validate([
            'forename' => 'required',
            'surname' => ''
        ]));

        return redirect('/people');
    }
```

My `routes/web.php` file had the following route:

```php
Route::put('/people/{id}', [PersonController::class, 'update']);
```

To fix this, the wildcard match should be the same as the model name.

```php
Route::put('/people/{person}', [PersonController::class, 'update']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
$items = ItemName::where($itemName)->update($request->all());
```

Comment: when i try your code, i got the error : SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name '[]'. (SQL: update [tbl_item_name] set [_token] = YaTMJPEoM1Bq9JTMyem0S23I1zp1JhnOTyr6Ak9y, [_method] = PUT, [inc] = a, [item_name] = 12345, [short_name] = 12345, [definition_eng] = , [definition_ind] = , [updated_at] = 2018-04-05 10:58:33.041 where [[]]] is null)

Comment: This is such bad practice and a huuuge security issue. This is bypassing eloquent completely and going straight to the database. You must use `->fill` to make use of mass-assignment. Imagine somebody changing the id field or some other field by adding extra form params....

Comment: use fill will update item but also add new item too @Mazzy

Comment: @DewaAditya That is because your `$itemName` is not a single instance then. Try dumping `$itemName` and let me know what the output is. The query you posted has an empty where clause indicating an issue with `$itemName`

Answer (score 0):

Try with fill instead of update.

```
 $itemName->fill($request->all());
 $itemName->save();
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Your way create new item instead of updating @Roshihegde

Comment: Have you tried ?  `$itemName = new itemName(); $itemName->fill($request->all());
 $itemName->save();` This will create a new item.

Comment: Sorry friend, I want to update the same item instead of adding items, your way is right for changing the item but also add new item @Roshihegde

Comment: @DewaAditya This answer is correct `$itemName->fill()->save();` is not creating a new record if `$itemName` is already known

Comment: but why if i use that code, will create new record, i dont know what the problem :(

Comment: i have add value when i dump this  $itemName->fill($request->all());
 $itemName->save();

Comment: `dd($itemName)`  check what it results in. If it results integer value then you have a  issue in bindings. It should result object

Comment: i have input the result in question above, please help to read that

Comment: Can u check  by adding router  `Route::update('ItemName/{id}', 'ItemNameController');` above the resource route Only for checking purpose, whether it works fine or not

Comment: sorry i meant `Route::put('ItemName/{id}', 'ItemNameController');`

Answer (score 0):

Note that the update() function responds false if your update values are the same as old record.